# Conflicting nested inherited traits

Tags: scala, traits

Suppose I have the following code:

```
trait Trait1 { 
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner1"
  }
}

trait Trait2 {
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner2"
  }
}

class Foo extends Trait1 with Trait2 {
  // I want Concrete1 to be a Trait1.Inner not a Trait2.Inner
  class Concrete1 extends Inner
  val c = new Concrete1
}

object Obj {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val foo = new Foo
    println(foo.c.name)
  }
}
```

When I mix in `Trait1` and `Trait2`, referring to `Inner` seems to default to the `Inner` type of whichever trait I mixin second; so when I call `Obj`'s `main` method it prints `Inner2`.  How can I refer to `Trait1.Inner` in `Foo`? All three of the following give compiler errors:

```
class Concrete1 extends Trait1.Inner
class Concrete1 extends Trait1$Inner
class Concrete1 extends Trait1#Inner
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
class Concrete1 extends Inner
```

Use this

```
class Concrete1 extends super[Trait1].Inner
```

That should get you what you want

Comment: That's great, I can now write class Concrete1 extends super[Trait1].Inner and class Concrete2 extends super[Trait2].Inner and have instances of both types of Inner in Foo.

Answer (score 4):

There are two namespaces within a template (template being the body of a class, object, or trait.)

1. Members: vals, vars, and defs and nested objects
2. Types: types aliases, nested traits and nested classes

When inheriting from multiple parent templates, conflicts in these namespaces are resolved through class linearization.

You could re-order your inheritance to bring the desired parent Inner into your class, or find an alternative design.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't occur to me that member traits would be overridden. Makes sense when you think about it!

Answer (score 3):

One option (if you can be invasive to the traits) is to define each Inner trait as a type member that has a non-conflicting name.

```
trait Trait1 {
  type Inner1 = Inner
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner1"
  }
}

trait Trait2 {
  type Inner2 = Inner
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner2"
  }
}

class Foo extends Trait1 with Trait2 {
  class Concrete1 extends Inner1
  class Concrete2 extends Inner2
  val c1 = new Concrete1
  val c2 = new Concrete2
}

object App extends Application {
  val foo = new Foo
  println(foo.c1.name) // Inner1
  println(foo.c2.name) // Inner2
}
```

If you cannot be invasive to the original traits (Trait1 and Trait2), you can extend them to define the type member.

```
trait Trait1 {
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner1"
  }
}
trait Trait2 {
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner2"
  }
}

trait Trait1a extends Trait1 {
  type Inner1 = Inner
}
trait Trait2a extends Trait2 {
  type Inner2 = Inner
}

class Foo extends Trait1a with Trait2a {
  class Concrete1 extends Inner1
  class Concrete2 extends Inner2
  val c1 = new Concrete1
  val c2 = new Concrete2
}
```

Another approach would be to use an intermediate trait to define your first concrete class:

```
trait Trait1 {
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner1"
  }
}
trait Trait2 {
  trait Inner {
    val name = "Inner2"
  }
}

trait FooIntermediate extends Trait1 {
  class Concrete1 extends Inner
}

class Foo extends FooIntermediate with Trait2 {
  class Concrete2 extends Inner
  val c1 = new Concrete1
  val c2 = new Concrete2
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd thought of doing type Inner1 = Inner. I hadn't thought of your other two options though; now I have too many choices :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not order the traits in the order you expect them to have precedence? The linearization of traits is not arbitrary, but specified.

Comment: Yes, I'd thought of doing that. But suppose I want to create a Concrete2 extends Trait2.Inner as well. What then?